# Win32 Log file appending with shared process writes

Tags: file, winapi, locking

I'm writing to a log file with a main application executable that I want additional executable's to append to as well.  I have CreateFileEx opening and writing correctly from all executables however when a child executable writes to that file (and it succeeds) and then the parent exe writes to the file afterwards it unfortunately overwrites what the child has written.  For example...

```
1) Parent opens log.
2) Parent writes 'Line A' to log
   Log: 'Line a\n'
3) Parent launches child executable
4) Child writes 'Child Line A' to log
   Log: 'Line A\nChild Line A\n'
5) Parent writes 'Line B' to log.
   Log: 'Line A\nLine B\n
```

I've been using LockFileEx / UnlockFileEx (set to offset 0 and length MAXDWORD) and even tried SetFilePointer to move that pointer to the end all without success. I.e. in the sequences above the write would equate to.

```
a) LockFileEx
b) SetFilePointer
c) ... write data ...
d) UnlockFileEx
```

Note: I've added correct permissions such as no buffering when I open the files etc, and even tried FlushFileBuffers to no success.

I would assume that somehow the parent file HANDLE isn't aware of the changes and thus SetFilePointer(fHandle,0,NULL,FILE_END) thinks it already is at the end.

Any ideas?

Thanks In Advance
- Tim

Comment: This happens when you try to roll your own, instead of using well tested system services. [Event Tracing for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803.aspx) does, what you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whats wrong with your code, you would have to provide its whole implementation - pseudo code description is too little. What I would suggest is instead of using file locking, to use mutex with normal regular file append, you can use wrapper class CMutexEx and CMutexExHelper as below then logging would look as follows:

```
  CMutexEx mtx("myapplogmutex", 250);
  CMutexExHelper mthHelper(mtx);
  if ( mthHelper.Aquire() ) {
    // Log to file, open it and after appending close
  }
```

I am not sure about how efficient this will be, but should at least be safe.

Implementation for CMutexEx and CMutexExHelper:

```
class CMutexEx {
public:
  HANDLE hMutex;
  DWORD dwWait;

  explicit CMutexEx(const TCHAR* szName, DWORD dwWait=25) : hMutex(0) { 
    hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, szName); 
    this->dwWait = dwWait;
  }

  bool Aquire() {    
    if ( !hMutex ) return false;

    DWORD dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, dwWait);
    if ( dwWaitResult != WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  void Release() {
    if ( hMutex )
      ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
  }

  ~CMutexEx() {
    CloseHandle(hMutex);
  }
};

class CMutexExHelper {
  CMutexEx& mtx;
public:
  CMutexExHelper(CMutexEx& p_mtx) : mtx(p_mtx) {
  }
  bool Aquire() {    
    return mtx.Aquire();
  }
  ~CMutexExHelper() {
    mtx.Release();
  }
};
```